# If $A$ , $B$ are dense in the metric space $X$ then,...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ is a metric space and $A$ and $B$ are two dense subset in $X$. Which is correct?

1. if $A$ is open, $A‎ \cap‎‎B$ is dense in $X$
2. if $A$ is closed in $X$, $A‎ \cap‎‎B=\emptyset$
3. $(A-B)\cup(B-A)$ is dense in $X$
4. $A^\circ‎\cup B^\circ$ is dense in $X$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: There are useful counterexamples with $X=\mathbb R$, $B=\mathbb Q$, and either $A=\mathbb R$ or $A=\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 1.

For 2, $A=\bar{A}=X\implies A\cap B= B=\emptyset$, which is contradictory for nontrivial $X$.

For 3, pick $B=A$, which again gives a contradiction for nontrivial $X$.

For 4, observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ contains no intervals. Then apply the same trick in 3.

Finally let us see why 1 holds. Let $x\in X$. Since $A$ is dense, $\exists \{a_n\}_n\subseteq A: a_n\to x$. Since $A$ is open, $\forall n, \exists \epsilon_n:B_{\epsilon_n}(a_n)\subseteq A$. Put $\forall n:\delta_n:=min\{1/n,\epsilon_n\}$. Then using the denseness of $B$, we may find $\forall n: b_n\in B_{\delta_n}(a_n)$. I'll leave it to you to show that $b_n\to x$ by using the triangle inequality.